# Linux kernel: how to load module last

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-modules

I wrote a kernel simple module, and I can select my module with `make menuconfig`. The module compiles and executes without a problem. Is there a method to force the kernel to load my module last - after all other modules? Are kernel modules loaded randomly or predictably? If they are loaded predictably, how can I specify that my module loads last? If I compile the module into the kernel, can this action somehow cause my module to load last of all modules?

Comment: Why do you want it to load last? This looks like a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377). What is it that you're really trying to solve?

Comment: No, this is not xy problem, I need certainty my module loaded afte other modules.

Comment: Actually can not depend all other modules on my module.

Comment: anybody can help me ? I need a solution . Note : I compiled module into kernel .